# Wait until user click a span then trigger AJAX request

Tags: jquery, django, materialize

Currently I'm working with simple AJAX put request when user change something in input field and click on "check" icon. The code below doesn't change icon from "edit" to "check", BUT when I delete a line `$.when($(icon).trigger("click")).then(function(){` with AJAX request then the icon will change.

I really appreciated any help with the appropriate jquery instruction

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.clickable-edit-icon').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var delete_id = $(this).closest('tr').data('contact-id');
        var icon = $(this).children();
        var input = $(this).parent().children('input');
        var input_text = $(input).text();

        if (icon.text() == "edit") {
            $(input).prop('disabled', false);
            $(icon).text("check");
            $.when($(icon).trigger("click")).then(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'edit/'+delete_id+'/',
                    method: 'PUT',
                    data: {},
                    contentType:'application/json',
                    error: function(result){},
                    success: function(result) {}
                });
            });
        }else{
            $(input).prop('disabled', true);
            $(icon).text("edit");
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML Structure**

```
<tr>
   <td id="contact-first-name">
      <input value="{{ contact.first_name }}" disabled>
          <span class='clickable-edit-icon'>
              <i class='tiny material-icons'>edit</i>
          </span>
   </td>
</tr>
```

If you wondering why I wrote `var input = $(this).parent().children('input');` instead of `var input = $(this).parent('input');` the reason is that input in second case is undefined.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking here. Perhaps an MCVE would make it clearer. Also note that putting `trigger()` in a `$.when()` handler is redundant as it's not an async process. Also you're double-wrapping several of your jQuery objects.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan You must know that now I'm learning jQuery and there are a lot of things that I have to learn :). Input and input_text variables will be needed to validate old and new string in futher code. Now I'm asking for a possibility to launch an AJAX function only when user is in edit mode and click "check" icon.

Comment: `If you wondering why I wrote` ....no, we wouldn't wonder that because those two statements are not equivalent. The first one looks for a different child who shares the same parent. The second one looks for the parent itself. You could potentially make use of [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to do this job though if you wanted.

Comment: The problem is that `.trigger()` doesn't return a Promise. Therefore there's nothing for `$.when()` to wait for. You may even have an error in your browser's Console about it - did you check? (you can press F12 to open it on most browsers). If you want to wait until the user has clicked on something, then you need to handle the "click" event of that something, and execute the AJAX request from there. If the thing should only sometimes be clickable, you can add and remove the click handler as needed, or put an `if` statement in the handler to check that it's ok to run the AJAX.

Comment: Yes, I checked a browser console and no errors appears. Thanks to your advice now I probably know how to do this. I'll write a new comment with results when it's done

Comment: If you solve it, you should write it as an Answer, not a comment. Answering your own question is both allowed and encouraged :-)

Comment: @ADyson I split click event handler into two parts. First part is responsible to handle click event for edit icon, then change span class name which should be handled by the second part, but... it doesn't work. Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rhdev/ctpmq21e/2/. Why second part with ```$(".clickable-check-icon")``` is not handled by the click?

Comment: It doesn't work because in the line `$(".clickable-check-icon").on('click',function(e){`, the `$(".clickable-check-icon")` is evaluated at the time the page loads. At that moment, there is no element with that class, so it doesn't match anything, and cannot attach the click handler to anything. To solve this, use "delegated event" syntax. See http://api.jquery.com/on/ - specifically the section called "direct and delegated events", and you should get the idea.

Comment: @ADyson But after I change this line to ```$("#contact-first-name").on('click','.clickable-check-icon',function(e){``` this function is automaticaly launch and when I press edit icon, the ajax request is executed. It works not as it should

Comment: ah...it's because you add the class to an existing element. jQuery detects that and, since you've already clicked on that element, assumes you want to execute the delegated handler instead. A better approach to this overall is probably to have two elements which you show and hide as needed, rather than changing the purpose of an existing element. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hre9ptgf/

Answer (score 1):

Mainly thanks to @ADyson the issue has been resolved. The next step I have to deal with is a 400 (Bad Request) PUT Method in Django but yes.. it's a diffrent story. Now AJAX is executed only when a 'check' icon/span was clicked and that was a goal of solution.

***JS File***

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".clickable-edit-icon").on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var span = $(this);
        var icon = $(this).children();
        var input = span.siblings('input');

        input.prop('disabled', false);
        span.siblings(".clickable-check-icon").show();
        span.hide();
    });

     $('.clickable-check-icon').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var span = $(this);
        var icon = $(this).children();
        var input = span.siblings('input');
        var edit_id = span.closest('tr').data('contact-id');

        input.prop('disabled', true);
        span.siblings(".clickable-edit-icon").show();
        span.hide();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'edit/'+edit_id+'/',
            method: 'PUT',
            data: {},
            contentType:'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function(result){},
            success: function(result) {
                $(icon).text("edit");
                $(input).prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

***HTML Structure***

```
<tr>
   <td id="contact-first-name">
      <input value="{{ contact.first_name }}" disabled>
          <span class='clickable-edit-icon'>
              <i class='tiny material-icons'>edit</i>
          </span>
          <span class='clickable-check-icon' style="display:none;">
              <i class='tiny material-icons'>check</i>
          </span>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the html structure, I've put it in a simple way:

```html
<div class='item'>
  <input tyle="text" />
  <span class="clickable-edit-icon editing">check</span>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.clickable-edit-icon').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var delete_id = $(this).closest('tr').data('contact-id');
        var icon = $(this);
        var input = $(this).parent().children('input');
        var input_text = $(input).text();
        if (icon.text() == "edit") {
            $(input).prop('disabled', false);
            $(icon).text("check");
            $.when(icon.trigger("click")).then(function(){
              $.ajax({
                    url: 'edit/'+delete_id+'/',
                    method: 'PUT',
                    data: {},
                    contentType:'application/json',
                    error: function(result){},
                    success: function(result) {}
                });
            });
        }else{
            $(input).prop('disabled', true);
            $(icon).text("edit");
        }
    });
};
```

Hope it helps with the thinking.

Comment: I think you've got this the wrong way round - see the title. OP wants to wait until the span is clicked, and then run the AJAX. You're running the AJAX and then clicking the span. Also, for what you're doing, $.when appears to be unnecessary.

Comment: I've changed it with html example and it works as I've understood what he needs

Comment: Not exacly @Will. There is a children element inside span tag ```<i class='tiny material-icons'>edit</i>```. I edited my previous post including a HTML structure. The code you placed does not work properly because after clicking on the span the icon does not change and the input is still disabled

Comment: `$.when(icon.trigger("click")).then(function(){` is still total nonsense here.